# What's the meaning of Goofy is a Dawg?

Tags: meaning

http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/978/if-pluto-is-a-dog-what-is-goofy

Says that goofy is a dawg, not a dog.

Well, dictionary says that dawg is black people.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dawg
So what's the connection?

http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Da&last=50 says that dawg also means dog. So what's Cecil meant when he said that Goofy is not a dog but a dawg?

Comment: He meant a dog with a Southern accent.

Comment: Why just pick that particular sense mentioned by dictionary? And why not consult a dictionary?

Comment: I suspect the use of "dawg" is meant to be humorous.  "Dawg" sounds like "dog", and also means someone who is "cool".  Given Goofy's...goofy behavior, there is a great humorous juxtaposition in calling him "dawg".

Comment: @Zibbobz: I'd agree and offer this reference in support of that view: **gawrsh** _ _ The word "gosh" as spelled when used by Goofy. ... _"Gawrsh!", Goofy said, that's a nice car you got there._ This also being from the Urban Dictionary, I don't know _why_ they don't include **dawg** _ _ The word "dog" as spelled when used of Goofy, and in similar situations evoking a Southern US flavour and/or humour.

Answer (score 4):

*Dawg* means *friend*, it can be used in the same way as *man* as in

> -- Hey man! 
>   -- 'Sup dawg?

it carries an impliation of "cool" as mentioned in the Merriam-Webster link you gave under the meaning you mention. Also see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dawg) (the relevant meaning(s) are in bold):

> Noun
>
> dawg (plural dawgs)
>
> Eye dialect spelling of dog; also hound dawg.
>
> That dawg won't hunt.
>
> **(slang) Dude, bud, pal. used to address a close male friend.**
>
> **Sup, dawg.**

As far as I know the word comes from the [African American vernacular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) and was popularized in the 90ies by various rappers.

The particular use you quote is just a play on *dog* and *dawg*. Goofy is obviously a dog but,unlike Pluto, he is a thinking (kinda), speaking character hence he is a *dawg* not a *dog*.

---

Actually, the word seems to be much older than I thought and its usage peaked in the beginning of the century according to [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dawg&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) Ngram:

[image]

I don't know what the meaning was at the time or if it was the same as the one used today.

Answer (score 2):

Read the article again, and you'll see "meanwhile adopting various aliases, including ***Dippy Dawg***,..." That is what Cecil is referring to, not any current vernacular use of the word.

Although I would have bet that he meant that Goofy is more a more anthropomorphized dog than Pluto, and therefore gets the upgrade to "dawg".